# Android scale image for XXHDPI

Tags: android, android-layout, hdpi

How can I make 2 separate layout folder for 
screens that are xxhdpi, and screens that are everything else?
Thanks!
I have right now just a layout folder for all my layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have folders under /res that are named as follows (where "xxhdpi" refers to the **Density**):

- layout
- layout-xxhdpi

However, you may actually be referring to the **Size** of the screen itself, which can be:

- layout
- layout-xlarge

as an example...

Please refer to the [Android Providing Resources docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more information on the flavors of folder names for resources.

Comment: Yes, density has absolutely nothing to do with screen size. The chances that you actually want a layout-xxhdpi folder are extremely low.

Comment: @MiStr thanks! this works, but what is the size for the nexus 7?